# How can I extract a vector from a list of text files

Tags: r, list, vector, text, extract

I have many different text files with the same structure (900*600 pixels). Now I would like to extract 900*600 vectors each containing one data point from each text file. 
For example I would like to have a vector from the position (x1,y1) with all the data points from all the text files.

Here you can see my code I have in order to generate a list with all the text files.

```
file.list = list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names=T)
df = data.frame( files= sapply(file.list, FUN = function(x)readChar(x, file.info(x)$size)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now "df" is a list containing all the text files. 
How can I extract now the different vectors with values from all the files?

This is my code so far. I need to define somehow a function (FUN).

```
files = lapply(df, FUN, header = F, sep="\t", skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I prepared a dummy data set.

```
a = matrix(c(15, 12,    37, 21, 37, 26, 33, 33, 27, 38, 32, 21, 24, 18,
             20, 14, 32, 56, 16, 7, 23, 14, 34, 42), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
b = matrix(c(14, 18,    34, 26, 37, 26, 32, 36, 21, 39, 32, 21, 22, 18,
             20, 16, 42, 50, 16, 7, 23, 12, 36, 40), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
c = matrix(c(10, 12,    34, 29, 31, 26, 30, 30, 20, 38, 36, 21, 29, 18,
             20, 10, 32, 59, 16, 1, 23, 10, 39, 49), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

file.list = list(a,b,c)
```

Here every variable corresponds to one textfile (listed in file.list). And instead of a 900*600 matrix there are 3*4 matrices.

Accordingly to your suggestions I implemented the the functions the following way.

```
cmbn = expand.grid(1:3, 1:4)
flen = length(file.list)
lapply(1:(nrow(cmbn)),function(t,lst,cmbn){
  return(sapply(1:flen,function(i,t1,lst1,cmbn1){
    return(lst1[[i]][cmbn1$Var1[t1],cmbn1$Var2[t1]])},t,lst,cmbn))}
  ,file.list,cmbn)
```

Comment: maybe you will need to create a matrix for each text file in the list (`matrix(byrow = TRUE, ncol = 900, nrow = 600)`), then iterate over each text file of the list using something like `strsplit(sep = "")`, that would return a list with a vector with all characters. Then you'd need to subset it `strsplit(sep = "")[[1]]` and assign it to the previously created matrix `matrix[] <- strsplit(sep = "")[[1]]`

Comment: I understand the approach by creating first the new matrix. But I don't understand how I can iterate it over each text file of the list. Do you have an idea how the function should look like which I could include within my "lapply" line.

Comment: Could you please update your question with sample data? It'd be useful to have data similar to "df", the list containing all the text files, so I can give it a try

Comment: Yes of course. no problem

Comment: @stefx what indices you want to extract from each of the file?

Comment: I would like to extract all indices as vectors. For example for the dummy data set we have three 3 text files summarised in a list. Now I would like to extract 12 vectors (3*4). The first vector would be: v1 = c(15, 14, 10). And the second one: v2 = c(12, 18, 12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:
It will take two loops. Not sure if this is the most optimized solution.

`cmbn` is the data.frame of co-ordinates.

`cmbn`  =  `expand.grid(1:3,1:4)`

```
#or `expand.grid(1:900,1:600)` in your case
```

`flen` = `length(file.list)`

`lst` will take `file.list`

```
lapply(1:(nrow(cmbn)),function(t,lst,cmbn)
                      {return(sapply(1:flen,function(i,t1,lst1,cmbn1){
                              return(lst1[[i]][cmbn1$Var1[t1],cmbn1$Var2[t1]])},t,lst,cmbn))
                      },file.list,cmbn)
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. As a result I get the error message  "Error in lst1[i][cmbn1$Var1[t1], cmbn1$Var2[t1]] :  incorrect number of dimension".
I adapted my text files in such a way that now additional text would disturb the loop function. They contain just the numbers within the matrix.

Comment: @stefx BTW, I have updated my code. I missed a square bracket earlier. Please try with the updated code.

Comment: @stefx you made changes in the code. In the statement with error use: `lst1[[i]][cmbn1$Var1[t1], cmbn1$Var2[t1]]`.Somehow, you removed the double `[[` brackets.

Comment: Yes of course. That is true. My mistake. 
Now the code returns all the vectors. But I get still an error message when I use my data. 
 Error in lst1[[i]][cmbn1$Var1[t1], cmbn1$Var2[t1]] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

And I do not know why. Because my text files within the list do only contain matrix. Now additional rows of text that could disturb the program.

Comment: For this code to run, you have to make sure the data is in the same format as in `file.list`. There could be multiple reasons that could lead the code to fail. Unless, you are able to reproduce the data on which you are running the code, I cannot you help you any more.

Comment: @stefx I hope you are using value of `cmbn = expand.grid(1:900,1:600)` as per your file format.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will rephrase and open a new question.